# Restrict element creation in XSLT if value is empty

Tags: java, xml, xslt-1.0

I wanted to create new element in target XML if and only if the element value of source XML is not empty. I can do this using below code. But, my problem is I have around 5k field to wrap with similar condition. Do we have any better way to handle this?

```
<xsl:if test="edi:po-num"> //wanted to avoid this for each element
    <xsl:element name="element">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">order_reference_number</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="edi:po-num"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

java code to transform:

```
Transformer trans = StylesheetCache.newTransformer(xslFilePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
trans.transform(source, new StreamResult(outputStream));
```

Comment: Define "empty". Your code checks for the existence of the `po-num` element, if that is your only concern then of course it should be easier to push existing nodes with `apply-templates` through a template that creates the `<element name="order_reference_number"><xsl:value-of select="."/></element>` or probably parameterize the `name` attribute value.

Comment: Please (in ALL XSLT questions) say which XSLT version you are using. There are many features in 2.0 and 3.0 which are not available to users who are stuck on 1.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay have updated the XSLT version...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a [mcve] showing an example of the input with several "fields" and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Your options in XSLT 1.0 are limited - XSLT 1.0 code tends to be verbose. But if it's really repetitive, then you could consider writing a meta-stylesheet - an XSLT stylesheet that generates your stylesheet from some higher-level description of what it needs to do.

Note also, your code will be a lot less verbose if you use literal result elements and attribute value templates rather than `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute`.